# "Так открывается новый – «золотой век», или второй период истории"?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная

> Но вот в XII столетии, а о Средних веках тут и пойдёт речь, Стефан
>   Неманя (1113–1200) свергает брата – ставленника Византии и объявляет
>   себя Великим жупаном. Так открывается новый – «золотой век», или
>   второй период истории, который продлится до покорения Сербии Турцией в
>   XIV столетии.

Тире после "новый". Я же не могу нарисовать:

*Так открывается новый – «золотой» – век, или второй период истории, который продлится до покорения Сербии Турцией в XIV столетии.*

Или могу?

Что делать с **Великим жупаном** - Вики хочет со строчной.

Comment: Век - начинается. Период - возможно что и открывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

Но вот в XII столетии, а о Средних веках тут и пойдёт речь, Стефан Неманя (1113–1200) свергает брата – ставленника Византии и объявляет себя Великим жупаном. Так открывается **новый «золотой век», или второй период истории, который продлится до покорения Сербии Турцией в XIV столетии**

Пояснения

1) **Золотой век** ― фразеологизм, который может писаться без кавычек (золотой век литературы). Здесь возможны варианты написания.

Все русские люди любили Иоанна, всею землею. Казалось, с его праведным царствием настал на Руси **новый золотой век**... [А. К. Толстой. Князь Серебряный (1861-1863)]

2) **Великий жупан**

Сте́фан І Нема́ня  (1113, Рибница — 13 февраля 1199, монастырь Хиландар) — сербский великий жупан Рашки, основатель династии Неманичей.

[https://howlingpixel.com/i-ru/Стефан_Неманя](https://howlingpixel.com/i-ru/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F)

Существовал титул ***великий жупан*** (строчная буква). Но, вероятно, в разных текстах возможны оба варианта написания. Объявить себя лучше **Великим жупаном**.  Это уже как бы не титул, а название первого и единственного лица в государстве, носящего этот титул. В крайнем случае можно заключить титул в кавычки (как дословное высказывание к *объявил*).

То же можно сказать и об названных нами сербских областях. Великий жупан, или князь Сербский, живший в городе Деснице, близ реки Дрины, был сначала главою, или по-древнеславянски и сербски старейшиною над всеми прочими жупанами; но после опустошения сербской земли болгарским царем Симеоном ( 924 г. ) возвысился над всеми прочими **жупан** Диоклейский, который стал называться королем. Наконец Стефан Неманя, отрасль **жупанского рода** из Дюклеи и родоначальник нового владетельного дома, основал в городе Расе сильное, независимое **Великое жупанство** и скоро соединил вокруг себя все сербские области, не выключая и Босны, хотя впрочем это соединение после опять несколько раз разрывалось. **[П. В. Киреевский. О древней русской истории. Письмо к М. П. Погодину (1845)]**